# Any guidelines on (deconstructive) reading of literarture?

Tags: discussion

- Is it OK to post a deconstruction of fictional literature?
- What would make it a philosophical question, rather than mere exegesis?

Comment: It seems fine as long as the concern is narrow and well-motivated theoretically; I'm curious what others think

Comment: @JosephWeissman i would want to try to answer this question [via two important poems] http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/28040?noredirect=1 is that enough ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a question [Is there a literature theory of science and math texts](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22891/is-there-a-literature-theory-of-science-and-math-texts) that seems similar that was well received by the community. So seems like a question kind of like that one would be fine.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll look at that link in a few days :)